# Why are 2 shadows forming?

Tags: optics

[image]

When I take a photo of my finger with flashlight on, why do I get 2 shadows instead of just one full black?

Comment: @user78406 Your finger is not in the focus of the lens. You photographed not a finger, but a screen with a shadow from a finger.

Comment: @AlexTrounev:  I wouldn't think that would be a problem, since the question is about the shadow.

Comment: Language clarification question: do you have a handheld flashlight *and* a camera flash? Or are you using "flashlight" to mean the bright light that comes on briefly and automatically when the camera takes a photo? Or do you have a handheld flashlight, and the camera's automatic flash is off? To American-English speakers, a "flashlight" is the standalone tool which British-English speakers usually call a "torch."

Answer (score 1):

You've two sources of light throwing two different shadows. The darker one is that off your flashlight, the lighter one is most likely from some other light source in the room, seemingly behind you to your left.

Another possible explanation would be that your flashligh somehow creates a weaker reflection that comes at another angle, however i don't think this is the case.

The take away is that evidently you have two light sources since you've two shadows.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that your flashlight has a reflector around the bulb, which can reflect the light from slightly different angles. For a sharper edged, single shadow, you need a single pinpoint light source. An ideal shadow would need a single point light source. It is also possible that your finger moved slightly during exposure time.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this just an illustration of:
[Umbra and Penumbra](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2068)